# AJAX call to API which returns list in JSON format using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, vue.js

I want to make an AJAX call to the free API https://reqres.in/api/users which returns the list in JSON format.
And I want to use Vue.js so that the result will be shown in the HTML, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Mi js is the following:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#users",
  data: {
    usuarios: []
}});

$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (usuarios){
    console.log(usuarios);
}})
```

And my HTML code is as follows.

```
 <div class="container text-center mt-4" id="userApp">
  <h1>Lista de usuarios</h1>

  <div id="users">
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4" v-for="usuario in data">
        <img 
          v-bind:src="usuario.avatar" 
          v-bind:alt="usuario.last_name">
        <p>{{ usuario.first_name }} - {{ usuario.last_name }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>

</div>
```

By doing that nothing appear on my page, and some images would have to appear and the name of each image (person) below.
Could you help me check where is the mistake?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: So what is logged in the console? And have you checked that the success function even gets called?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. I'm still a newbie learning the basics

Comment: *the result will be shown in the HTML, but for some reason it doesn't work* - it doesn't work for a very good reason, because you didn't assign the result anywhere but output it to the console. You may want to cover basics of JS before moving to Vue. As for the console, F12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, I would recommend you don't use jQuery at all and bring in Axios, but here is how you could accomplish it if you insist on using jQuery.

Good luck in your project!

[image]

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="usersVueApp" class="container">  
      <div class="row"> 
        <div class="card col-3 p-2 m-3" v-for="(user,index) in users" :key="index">
          <img class="card-img-top":src="user.avatar" :alt="user.first_name">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text"> 
               <a :href="`mailto:${user.email}`" class="btn btn-primary">Email {{user.first_name}}</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var app = new Vue({ 
      el: "#usersVueApp",

      data: function(){
        return { 
          users: [] 
        };
      },

      mounted : function() {
        this.loadUsers();
      },

      methods : {
        loadUsers : function () {
          const _this = this;
          $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "https://reqres.in/api/users",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (users){
              _this.users = users.data;
           }});
        }
      }
    });
    </script>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: Awesome, notice that the crux of this solution, or what you were missing, is that you need to make the AJAX call within the scope of cue and then assign it to a local data variable.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to accomplish this is through something like Axios (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-axios).

I would discourage using jQuery along with Vue.js, keep it clean.

From Axios' example in the link above:

```
// main.ts
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

const app = createApp(App).use(store)
app.use(VueAxios, axios)
app.provide('axios', app.config.globalProperties.axios)  // provide 'axios'
app.mount('#app')

// App.vue
import { inject } from 'vue'

export default {
  name: 'Comp',
  setup() {
    const axios: any = inject('axios')  // inject axios

    const getList = (): void => {
      axios
        .get(api)
        .then((response: { data: any }) => {
          console.log(response.data)
        });
    };

    return { getList }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!
Actually this is for an excercise and I'm not allowed to use other tools. And I don't really understand axios.
Do you know how to do it just using jQuery and Vuej.js ?